# Deploy a rails app from a git repo

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, deployment

I have a git bare repo on production server:

```
/home/username/railsapp.git
```

Now I would like to have a copy to use with mod_rails. Something like:

```
/home/username/railsapp/
```

What is the best way to copy the files from the repo to the "production" directory?
Should I do something like a shallow clone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The usual way to "pull" the files out of a bare git repository is indeed to clone the repo and then pull it every time you need to update it.

You can also use hooks to automatically update the code used in production when it's pushed to the repository, but that's another topic.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using [Capistrano](https://github.com/capistrano/capistrano/wiki), which wraps up the commands to deploy projects from source control (primarily Git).

In short, you configure your environment(s) (multi-stage), indicate which branch should be tracked and when deploying it will clone directly on your deployment machine from your source control (with various caching options).

In addition to that you can wrap in anything else you need bound in to the process, cache clears, database migrations, etc.

---

With regards to Rails, there'll certainly be Capistrano recipes to get you going that will cache clear, rake and perform other basic tasks on demand.